# Spam filter using Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, vectorization

I`m trying to make a simple spam filter using python 2.7 and scikit-learn. So, I have a set of letters for train and a set of letters for test. Firstly, I want to vectorize training set and fit logistic regression using it, then vectorize each letter in test set and put them into classifier separately.

```
import codecs
import json
import os
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn import linear_model

def classify(mail, vectorizer, logreg):
    vect_mail = vectorizer.transform(mail)
    res = logreg.predict(vect_mail)
    return res

def make_output(test_dir, vectorizer, logreg):
   with codecs.open('test.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as out:
       for f in os.listdir(test_dir):
           mail = json.load(open(os.path.join(test_dir, f)), 'utf-8')
           result = classify(mail['body'].encode('ascii','ignore'), vectorizer, logreg)
           out.write(u'%s\t%s\n' % (f, result))

def read_train(train_dir):
    for f in os.listdir(train_dir):
        with open(os.path.join(train_dir, f), 'r') as fo:
            mail = json.load(fo, 'utf-8')
            yield mail

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_mails = list(read_train('spam_data/train'))
    corpus = list()
    is_spam = list()

    for mail in train_mails:
        corpus.append(mail['body'].encode('ascii','ignore'))
        is_spam.append(mail['is_spam'])
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    cnt_vect = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
    logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
    logreg.fit(cnt_vect, is_spam)
    make_output('spam_data/test', vectorizer, logreg)
```

But `res = logreg.predict(vect_mail)` returns a list, not one meaning. So, I guess, predictor interprets `vect_mail` like sample of documents of one word, not like a document with many words. How should I rewrite this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the sklearn's documentation, [`CountVectorizer.transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.transform) accepts not a single document to transform, but an **iterable** of documents. Since a string in Python is an iterable of its characters, `transform` generates as many "documents" as there are characters in the string.

In order to fix this issue, pass a single-element list to the `transform`:

```
vect_mail = vectorizer.transform([mail])
```